# SQL Server 2019 Scalar function returns first 9 characters not full result

Tags: sql, t-sql, user-defined-functions, inline, sql-server-2019

A Scalar function working properly on all SQL versions except on compatibility level SQL 2019 (cl 150), it returns only the first 9 characters of the result string.

If I change back to cl 140 no problem and full result is returned.

My code used

```
Create table Table1(ClientId varchar(255), [CompanyName] nvarchar(255), Place nvarchar(255) )
GO
Create table Table2(ClientId varchar(255), [Christianname] nvarchar(255), [prefix] varchar(15),Place nvarchar(255), [SirName] nvarchar(255))

GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnClientName] (@ClientId varchar(255))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (left(@ClientId,2) = 'RP')  RETURN
    (
        SELECT   [CompanyName] + ' settled ' + case len(ltrim(rtrim(Place))) when 0 then '*' else (IsNull([Place], '*')) end
        FROM     [dbo].[Table1]
        WHERE    ([ClientId] = @ClientId)
    )

    IF (left(@ClientId,2) = 'NP')  RETURN
    (
        SELECT   replace(IsNULL([Christianname],'* ') + ' ' + IsNULL([prefix]+' '+[SirName], [SirName]) ,'  ',' ') + ' living ' +  case len(rtrim(ltrim(Place))) when 0 then '*' else  (IsNull([Place], '*'))end
        FROM     [dbo].[Table2]
        WHERE    ([ClientId] = @ClientId)
    )

    RETURN 'no results'
END
GO
```

Result in compatibility level version prior to SQL 2019(CL150)

```
Anybody the Unknown living Someplace
```

Result in compatibility level version SQL 2019(CL150)

```
Anybody t
```

Anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: This might be an inlining issue, however, without sample data, we can't test this.

Comment: Also apply the latest CU as there have been several fixes related to inlineing of TVFs: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100809

Comment: Thanks all for the response! The KB fixed it!
issue can be closed as solved

Answer (score 0):

It is an inlineing issue for TVFs. The fix is in the
Cumulative Update Package 8 for SQL Server 2019 - KB4577194

[www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100809](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100809)

#Updateyoursytemfrequently

Comment: What do you mean this was fixed in package 8? Your question says you're using update 15...

Comment: cl was abbreviate  for compatibility level. not update.
Hope this will clarify it

Comment: 150, sorry forgot the trailing 0. Have edited in the original post